# Combining date based on four different tables in SQL environment

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, date

Master_table                           Table_A

```
 ID   Problem    Date              ID   Problem     Date
101      123    01-02-1993        101       123   01-02-1993
101      124                      101       124
102      125                      102       125   07-02-1994
103      126    08-22-1999        103       126   08-22-1999
103      131                      103       131   08-09-1999
```

Table_B                                Table_C

```
 ID   Problem    Date              ID   Problem     Date
101      124                      101       124   
102      125    06-30-1994        102       125
103      126    08-22-1999        103       131   08-08-1999
103      131    08-09-1999        106       137   02-02-1987
106      137    01-02-1987        110       145   12-22-1995
```

I need to create a new table named ‘final_table’ such that all observations in Master_table have a date. Rule for achieving this: Date from Master_table will be used as the date when Date exists. Otherwise, the minimum Date from Table_A, Table_B and Table_C will be used. If Date is missing in all the tables then drop the observation.

Desired Output

```
ID   Problem    Date              
101      123    01-02-1993                            
102      125    06-30-1994                  
103      126    08-22-1999        
103      131    08-08-1999
```

What I've tried

```
SELECT ID, Problem, MIN(Date) as Date
FROM
(   SELECT ID, Problem, Date
    FROM Table_A
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, Problem, Date
    FROM Table_B
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, Problem, Date
    FROM Table_C
) as subQuery
Delete From table Where Date IS NULL
```

Comment: @Jens I tried, but I didn't quite get the desired output. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @RacilHilan yes this is exactly my aim

Comment: Since you've already tried it and didn't get the desired output, then you know it's wrong. So why did you say in your question *not sure if it's correct*? :-)

Comment: Your query can be the first step in the solution, it's mainly missing the joins between the tables. But the IDs in your tables are not unique, which indicates either something missing in your question (the real unique ID or parent table), or your database design is incorrect. I'm not sure you can get what you want with this structure. Perhaps I'm too tired to think :-)

Answer (score 0):

Seeme you need  a union between the 3 tables this way

```
    select id, problem, data
    from Table_A
    where date is not null
    union 
    select id, problem, min(data)
    from Table_B
    group by id, problem
    where date is not null
    union
    select id, problem, min(data)
    from Table_B
    group by id, problem
    where date is not null
```